# R-markdown - different font size in different sections

Tags: fonts, r-markdown, size

I would like to have different font size in different sections of r markdown, here is an example:

````
```{r psection 1}
# I would like to have font size 20
print("Hello, World!")
```


```{r psection 2}
# I would like to have font size 10
print("Hello, World!")
```
````

I wonder if this is possible? So far my understanding that font size must state the same for whole document (except headers).

Comment: Do you want to render to html? or PDF?

Comment: @J_F To HTML ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to wrap your sections into fenced divs and to use CSS to style the sections.

````
::: {.large}
```{r psection 1}
# I would like to have font size 20
print("Hellow, World!")
```
:::


::: {.normal-size}
```{r psection 2}
# I would like to have font size 10
print("Hellow, World!")
```
:::

<style>
.normal-size pre {
  font-size: 10pt;
}
.large pre {
  font-size: 20pt;
}
</style>
````

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Missing size units and a more specific selector. Fixed.